# How do you resize elements to fit within a view, then align these views in a VGrid?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to create a grid of 'tiles' of products that you can scroll through. I am fetching the data for these 'tiles' from firebase with sample images and text and they are being created however the dimensions of each 'tile' varies. I want them to all be the same size and aligned with each other. The issue seems to occur when there is more text. I want it to change the dimensions of the title, subtitle, image etc. to fit within the 'tile' (which should be a fixed size).

At the moment these 'tiles' vary in size and they are not properly aligned. (See attached photo)

The code for the tile view for products is as follows:

```
VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {

    WebImage(url: URL(string: productData.product_image))
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .frame(width: 160, height: 225)
        .cornerRadius(15)
        .clipped()
        .padding(5)
        
       
    Text(productData.product_name)
        .font(.title2)
        .fontWeight(.bold)
        .foregroundColor(.black)
        .padding()

        
    Text(productData.product_type)
        .font(.caption)
        .foregroundColor(.gray)
        .lineLimit(2)
        .padding()
}
```

And the code for the VGrid that loops through and displays the product tiles is as follows:

```
ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false, content: {
    
    Spacer()
    
    LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(),spacing: 10), count: 2),spacing: 20){
        
        ForEach(HomeModel.filteredProduct){product in
            
            // Product View...
            
            ProductView(productData: product)
                .background(.white)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15, style: .continuous))
                .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.4), radius: 3, x: 1, y: 1)
                .contentShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15, style: .continuous))
                .onTapGesture {
                    
                    withAnimation(.easeIn){
                        
                        selectedProduct = product
                        show.toggle()
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    Spacer()
        .padding()
        .padding(.top,10)
})
.padding(.top, 20)
```

Below is a photo of the current issue:

[image: Photo of issue]

These tiles need to be the same size regardless of the length of titles, size of images etc. They should also be aligned. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: This needs a [Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I suspect the culprit may be using `.flexible()`, but we can't run your code to test things without a major rewrite. The code you post must be full self contained.

Comment: May be setting a maxHeight to your product view or a constant height.